# Why can't we discover tag badge awardees for a given tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-badges

The tag page has a 'Top Users' link that show the top answering / questioning users.  However, there is no way to discover the tag badge awardees.

For example, here is what I see on the bash tag [Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/topusers) page:

[image: Top users of the “bash” tag]

I want to discover the gold badge holders for bash, there is no easy way.  Remember, the top contributors may or may not have earned a tag badge - since tag badges depend on total votes as well as the number of answers.  This becomes a common problem for Stack Overflow for Teams where we have a lot of low-trafficked company specific tags.

I think it is good for the tag page to have a place for tag badge holders.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/928172?badge=bash

Comment: All these clunky workarounds just reinforce the benefits of having this feature btw.

Comment: @BoltClock I take offense on calling my beautiful query "clunky" ...

Comment: And what information are you hoping to obtain from this badge info that isn't already conveyed by the top answerer page?

Comment: @Tezra: Top Users lists users by total votes and number of posts (and they are not separately sortable).  Since badges are based on BOTH votes and number of posts, it is better to have a separate place to view the badge holders.

Comment: And there is. The data SE provides a mechanism to extract info not provided by the main UX. @rene's query is extremely concise and does the job. It's also a reason folks can name the queries and we can search for them. Seems like a good balance to me.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

It would be a nice addition to the top users page, but you can easily check the requirements on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and then navigate to the top users page and check which user satisfies these requirements, according to the upvotes and number of answers.

[image]

Comment: And when there are more badges awarded than users listed on the top users page?

Answer (score 40):

As a workaround, you can visit the [profile page of somebody you know to have the gold tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson?tab=badges) (found via the Top Users link), [click on the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/863/bash?userid=26428) and then on the link 'Others with this badge', which leads you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/863/bash):

[image]

Oh, by the way, congratulations!

---

Alternatively, use the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-by-tag#order=desc&max=gold&sort=rank&inname=bash&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to find the ID of the badge (863):

[image]

and navigate to `https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/{badge_id}`.